# Keyboard not showing?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using the Eclair version.I installed Android plug-in to Eclipse in my office desktop at that time the emulator shows the keyboard on right side. But now I installed ADT plug-in to my Laptop there is no keyboard on right, laptop using windows 7 OS. how to solve this problem ?